# $this->request->referer() is not working in cakephp 3.2 from email link

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.2

I am doing a cakephp project.
I was stuck here.
I want to get the previous url in cakephp 3.2,but its not working.
Here the link is present in email ,after clicking upon that link i will redirect to login page and after login ,i wnato to redirect to that previous url means the url present in mail only.
I have written the below code to do it.

```html
 $rU = $this->request->referer();
        if (!stristr($rU, "users/login") && !stristr($rU, "login") && !stristr($rU, "users/register") && !stristr($rU, "register") && !stristr($rU, "appadmins") && !stristr($rU, "js") && !stristr($rU, "css") && !stristr($rU, "ajax")) {
            $this->request->session()->write('visited_page',$rU);
        }
```

Plesae suggst me.
Any suggestion will highly appreciate.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Cakephp provides the feature to redirect users back to where they came from.

Its `AuthComponent::redirectUrl()`

After the login redirect them to redirectUrl like below
`$this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl())`

For more info visit [here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#redirecting-users-after-login)

Answer (score 1):

First in AppController.php. Inside beforeFilter function store previous url in session

```
public function beforeFilter(){
  $url = Router::url(NULL, true); //complete url
  if (!preg_match('/login|logout/i', $url)){ // Restrict login and logout actions
    $this->Session->write('prevUrl', $url);
  }
}
```

Use where you need to redirect

```
if ($this->Session->read('prevUrl')){
$this->redirect($this->Session->read('prevUrl'));
exit;
}
```

This is working in cakephp 2.6 change beforeFilter function in cakephp 3 as

```
public function beforeFilter(\Cake\Event\Event $event){
  $url = Router::url(NULL, true); //complete url
if (!preg_match('/login|logout/i', $url)){ // Restrict login and logout actions
    $session = $this->request->session();
    $session->write('prevUrl', $url);
 }
}
```

Use where you need to redirect

```
$session = $this->request->session();
if($session->read('prevUrl')){
   $this->redirect($session->read('prevUrl'));
   exit;
}
```